# Como fazer um ListView Dinâmico gerado com dados do BarCodeScan?

Tags: android

Sou iniciante em Java/Android, e estou querendo fazer com que um listview seja criado a partir dos "Scans" feitos utilizando o ZXing.

No caso eu tenho a tela com o botão para escanear e nela é exibida a resposta do  scan, quero colocar as respostas de mais de um scan em um listview como uma pilha, uma encima da outra, como faço isso?

Esta é a MainActivity (padrão do exemplo do Zxing).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    private TextView txResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txResult);


    }

    public void callZXing(View view){
        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(REQUEST_CODE == requestCode && RESULT_OK == resultCode){
            txResult.setText("RESULTADO: "+data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")+" ("+data.getStringExtra("SCAN_FORMAT")+")");
        }
    }
}
```

Obrigado a todos que puderem ajudar.

Comment: Alguém poderia mostrar o caminho para fazer isso?

Comment: so não entendi a parte do R.layout.my_text_view,este TextView vc colocou dentro de outro arquivo xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou recomendar usar RecyclerView ao invés de ListView pois o RecyclerView da suporte a tudo que um ListView faz de forma mais eficiente.

Também gostaria de recomendar a leitura abaixo pra que possa entender o código:
http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/material/lists-cards.html

Primeiramente, você precisa importar a lib do RecyclerView, vá no seu build.gradle:

```
dependencies
    {
        ...
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    }
```

No seu activity_main.xml você vai precisar adicionar um RecyclerView:

```
...
<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
...
```

Na sua MainActivity.java será necessário iniciar o RecyclerView e seu adapter:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    ...
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    List<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter( mData );
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter( mAdapter );
    ...
}
...
}
```

Seu Adapter precisará possuir uma função para adicionar novos dados obtidos, no caso a public void addData( String newData ):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<String> mDataset;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(List<String> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ...
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((TextView)v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.mTextView.setText( mDataset.get( position) );

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public void addData( String newData ){
    mDataset.add( newData );
}

}
```

Lembre-se de criar o layout dos seus itens da lista, dentro da pasta res/layouts crie um arquivo chamado my_text_view com apenas um TextView com o layout desejado.

Agora o RecyclerView e seu Adapter estão corretamente configurados e você deve passar os novos scans obtidos para o adapter e avisar que um novo elemento foi inserido. Para enviar o valor escaneado você usará a função que criamos no adapter, e para avisar que um novo elemento foi inserido basta chamar a função notifyDataSetChanged( ) do adapter. Logo, sua onActivityResult ficaria assim:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(REQUEST_CODE == requestCode && RESULT_OK == resultCode){
        mAdapter.addData("RESULTADO: "+data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")+" ("+data.getStringExtra("SCAN_FORMAT")+")");
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged( );
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente explicação Matheus, agradeço a atenção.

Porém, após inserir tudo conforme você citou, neste parte:

@Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_text_view,parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    }

O "v" entre (), fica destacado com a seguinte mensagem: 

ViewHolder (android.widget.TextView) in ViewHolder cannot be applied  to (android.view.View)

o que poderia ser? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Pra solucionar isso você precisa dar um cast no View v: **ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder( (TextView) v);**

Comment: Funcionou, agora tem outro detalhe que esqueci de citar acima. 

No meu onActivityResult, o addData não está sendo reconhecido: 

mAdapter.addData("RESULTADO: "+data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")+" ("+data.getStringExtra("SCAN_FORMAT")+")");  

E ele está no MyAdapter:
    public void addData(String newData){
        mDataset.add( newData );
    }

O que poderia ser também?

Comment: Isso aconteceu por ser um objeto RecyclerView.Adapter em **private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;**. Altere isso para **private MyAdapter mAdapter;**. Como sua classe MyAdapter extende RecyclerView.Adapter ela possui todos os seus métodos, porém o inverso não é válido, a função addData é uma função da MyAdapter.

Comment: Obrigado, fiz conforme explicou. Compilei, agora a tela inicial continua do jeito que tava, eu escaneio e fica mostrando só aquele item escaneado, quando escaneio outro ele toma o lugar do primeiro, não está montando a lista, poderia me auxiliar novamente?

Comment: Bom, dei uma olhada no código e não fui capaz de identificar o erro. O que eu sugiro é botar uns breakpoints na getItemCount( ) e na onBindViewHolder( ) pra ver se seu mData está com os dados corretos, a getItemCount retorna o número de elementos na mData e a onBindViewHolder é chamada uma vez pra cada elemento do mData. Se estiver tudo correto precisaria olhar seu código e acho melhor criar outra pergunta ou procurar alguma pergunta previamente feita no stackoverflow ou algum tutorial no Google que possa te apontar pro erro.